# Rewrite rule that can rewrite %26 to a special char sequence

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

My site serves up documents from tocmat that sometimes have `&`'s in the file names.

So

`nick&janes.doc`

Here is the URL we access it with:

`http://mysite.com/sub/nick%26janes.doc`

For some reason our version of Apache + OpenSSL fails to re-write this correctly due to some bug. So the %26 becomes an & and then the request is all broken, because `http://mysite.com/sub/nick&janes.doc`

Upgrading OpenSSL will fix the problem, but this unfortunately isn't an option for several months.

As a work-around, we are trying to create a rewrite rule that can turn any `%26` into a special character sequence.... let's say `___--___`. Then on Tomcat, we can use a filter to fix the URLs and thus no more problem.

Anyone know how I can write such a rewrite rule?

Comment: Comment from #httpd:  if there is a set maximum number of iterations, then yes, you can do it with a rewrite rule. one rewrite rule can replace one %26 with something else, so if you had nicks%26janes%26erics%26johns.doc, you'd need 3 rewrite rules. so, it's possible, but it'll look stupid :) the other, and more sane option, would be to use mod_lua/perl/python to rewrite the URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)&(.*)$ $1__-__$2 [N]
```

This turns `foo%26bar` to `foo__-__bar`

At that point you can use a Tomcat filter to change any URL with `__-__` back to %26